# RevenueCat empty Offerings

Tags: flutter, dart, revenuecat

This is really frustrating. I followed every step carefully and even created service accounts multiple times and it's been weeks. None of the similar issues worked for me. I'm so confused on how to make this work. Uploaded bundle with BILLING permission in closed testing. Created tracks and testers and all. typed every single character every second of the product ID in subscription to use in Revenue cat. I don't know if there's something to match with the Offering's identifier.
No errors whatsoever. It's just empty offerings.

anyone can just drop here similar issues? This should be a great alternative to in_app_purchase but it doesn't work. There's only 1 youtube video that implemented this and it's full of shortcuts.

prices in subscription - OK
match product ID to revenue products - OK
permission - OK

Comment: How are you installing your app? Are you downloading the closed testing version? Or are you installing from Android Studio? If installing from Android Studio make sure the package name is the same as in Play Console (you are not adding any .debug at the end or anything like that)

Comment: Since I'm using flutter I use VS Code and i run the app using flutter run